# Find rows in table regexp - mysql

Tags: mysql

How to find rows in table which not contain @ symbol ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [NOT LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_not-like) ('%@%')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name NOT REGEXP '.*@.*';
```